# Android smali edition : Set jpeg quality?

Tags: java, android, smali

Hello devs around here.

Recently I modified a port of ColorOS Camera to make it work on my device (Xiaomi Mi4).
Actually this app works pretty well with only XML editions. But the thing that sorts out is that this app uses default android jpeg compression (jpegquality = 85% in my case)

I just decided to modify smali files to change this. I already modified burst mode to capture jpeg with 100% quality (changed value 0x4B to 0x64 to get 100% quality instead 75% on burst mode and it worked)
Problem comes when I try to edit other lines to get jpeg quality = 100% even with normal shoting mode.

Can somebody help me and explain me? (please don't forget that I'm a beginner, and I spent lot of hours to try editing)

Here is the smali code (from CameraProcessManager.smali)

```
.method public setCaptureJpegOrientationAndQuality(I)V
.locals 4
.param p1, "orientation"    # I

.prologue
.line 1338
iput p1, p0, Lcom/oppo/camera/CameraProcessManager;->mJpegRotation:I

.line 1339
iget-boolean v1, p0, Lcom/oppo/camera/CameraProcessManager;->mbBurstShot:Z

if-eqz v1, :cond_0

.line 1340
const/16 v0, 0x64

.line 1345
.local v0, "jpegQuality":I
:goto_0
iget-object v1, p0, Lcom/oppo/camera/CameraProcessManager;->mParameterManager:Lcom/oppo/camera/ParameterManager;

iget v2, p0, Lcom/oppo/camera/CameraProcessManager;->mJpegRotation:I

invoke-virtual {v1, v2}, Lcom/oppo/camera/ParameterManager;->setRotation(I)V

.line 1346
iget-object v1, p0, Lcom/oppo/camera/CameraProcessManager;->mParameterManager:Lcom/oppo/camera/ParameterManager;

invoke-virtual {v1, v0}, Lcom/oppo/camera/ParameterManager;->setJpegQuality(I)V

.line 1347
const-string v1, "CameraProcessManager"

new-instance v2, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

invoke-direct {v2}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;-><init>()V

const-string v3, "setCaptureJpegOrientationAndQuality(),mJpegRotation:"

invoke-virtual {v2, v3}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

move-result-object v2

iget v3, p0, Lcom/oppo/camera/CameraProcessManager;->mJpegRotation:I

invoke-virtual {v2, v3}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

move-result-object v2

const-string v3, " jpegQuality:"

invoke-virtual {v2, v3}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

move-result-object v2

invoke-virtual {v2, v0}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

move-result-object v2

invoke-virtual {v2}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->toString()Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v2

invoke-static {v1, v2}, Landroid/util/Log;->v(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I

.line 1348
return-void

.line 1342
.end local v0    # "jpegQuality":I
:cond_0
iget v1, p0, Lcom/oppo/camera/CameraProcessManager;->mCameraId:I

const/4 v2, 0x2

invoke-static {v1, v2}, Landroid/media/CameraProfile;->getJpegEncodingQualityParameter(II)I

move-result v0

.restart local v0    # "jpegQuality":I
goto :goto_0
.end method
```

Here is corresponding java code (I know that I can't edit java code made from smali, sadly, that would be easier)
From dex2jar :

```
  public void setCaptureJpegOrientationAndQuality(int paramInt)
  {
    this.mJpegRotation = paramInt;
    if (this.mbBurstShot) {}
    for (paramInt = 75;; paramInt = CameraProfile.getJpegEncodingQualityParameter(this.mCameraId, 2))
    {
      this.mParameterManager.setRotation(this.mJpegRotation);
      this.mParameterManager.setJpegQuality(paramInt);
      Log.v("CameraProcessManager", "setCaptureJpegOrientationAndQuality(),mJpegRotation:" + this.mJpegRotation + " jpegQuality:" + paramInt);
      return;
    }
  }
```

And here is an other point of view from Virtuous Ten Studio :

```
    public void setCaptureJpegOrientationAndQuality(int i)
    {
        mJpegRotation = i;
        int j;
        if (mbBurstShot)
            j = 100;
        else
            j = CameraProfile.getJpegEncodingQualityParameter(mCameraId, 2);
        mParameterManager.setRotation(mJpegRotation);
        mParameterManager.setJpegQuality(j);
        Log.v("CameraProcessManager", (new StringBuilder()).append("setCaptureJpegOrientationAndQuality(),mJpegRotation:").append(mJpegRotation).append(" jpegQuality:").append(j).toString());
    }
```

I would like to keep jpegorentation setting but change jpegquality to be always 100%

Thanks a lot in advance if someone is able to help me and give some explanations =)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:

```
if burstmode (v0) = 100% (.line 1340 const/16 v0, 0x64)
if other mode (v1) = cond0 (end of the public method)
```

So I had to replace `cond0` value by:

```
 .line 1340 const/16 v0, 0x64
```

And it gives:

```
.method public setCaptureJpegOrientationAndQuality(I)V
    .locals 4
    .param p1, "orientation"    # I

    .prologue
    .line 1338
    iput p1, p0, Lcom/oppo/camera/CameraProcessManager;->mJpegRotation:I

    .line 1339
    iget-boolean v1, p0, Lcom/oppo/camera/CameraProcessManager;->mbBurstShot:Z

    if-eqz v1, :cond_0

    .line 1340
    const/16 v0, 0x64

    .line 1345
    .local v0, "jpegQuality":I
    :goto_0
    iget-object v1, p0, Lcom/oppo/camera/CameraProcessManager;->mParameterManager:Lcom/oppo/camera/ParameterManager;

    iget v2, p0, Lcom/oppo/camera/CameraProcessManager;->mJpegRotation:I

    invoke-virtual {v1, v2}, Lcom/oppo/camera/ParameterManager;->setRotation(I)V

    .line 1346
    iget-object v1, p0, Lcom/oppo/camera/CameraProcessManager;->mParameterManager:Lcom/oppo/camera/ParameterManager;

    invoke-virtual {v1, v0}, Lcom/oppo/camera/ParameterManager;->setJpegQuality(I)V

    .line 1347
    const-string v1, "CameraProcessManager"

    new-instance v2, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    invoke-direct {v2}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;-><init>()V

    const-string v3, "setCaptureJpegOrientationAndQuality(),mJpegRotation:"

    invoke-virtual {v2, v3}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    move-result-object v2

    iget v3, p0, Lcom/oppo/camera/CameraProcessManager;->mJpegRotation:I

    invoke-virtual {v2, v3}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    move-result-object v2

    const-string v3, " jpegQuality:"

    invoke-virtual {v2, v3}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    move-result-object v2

    invoke-virtual {v2, v0}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    move-result-object v2

    invoke-virtual {v2}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->toString()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v2

    invoke-static {v1, v2}, Landroid/util/Log;->v(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I

    .line 1348
    return-void

    .line 1342
    .end local v0    # "jpegQuality":I
    :cond_0
    .line 1340
    const/16 v0, 0x64

    .restart local v0    # "jpegQuality":I
    goto :goto_0
.end method
```